# Algorithm puzzle interview

Tags: algorithm

I found this interview question, and I couldn't come up with an algorithm better than O(N^2 * P):

> Given a vector of P natural numbers (1,2,3,...,P) and another vector of length N whose  elements are from the first vector, find the longest subsequence in the second vector, such  that all elements are uniformly distributed (have the same frequency).

Example : (1,2,3) and (1,**2,1,3,2,1,3,1,2,3**,1). The longest subsequence is in the interval [2,10], because it contains all the elements from the first sequence with the same frequency (1 appears three times, 2 three times, and 3 three times).

The time complexity should be O(N * P).

Comment: Does the subsequence have to be consecutive?

Comment: Yes, a subsequence V[i..j] is composed of the elements : V[i],V[i+1],..V[j].

Answer (score 49, accepted):

"Subsequence" usually means noncontiguous. I'm going to assume that you meant "sublist".

Here's an O(N P) algorithm <strike>assuming we can hash</strike> (assumption not needed; we can radix sort instead). Scan the array keeping a running total for each number. For your example,

```
  1  2  3
 --------
  0  0  0
1 
  1  0  0
2
  1  1  0
1
  2  1  0
3
  2  1  1
2
  2  2  1
1
  3  2  1
3
  3  2  2
1
  4  2  2
2
  4  3  2
3
  4  3  3
1
  5  3  3
```

Now, normalize each row by subtracting the minimum element. The result is

```
 0: 000
 1: 100
 2: 110
 3: 210
 4: 100
 5: 110
 6: 210
 7: 100
 8: 200
 9: 210
10: 100
11: 200.
```

Prepare two hashes, mapping each row to the first index at which it appears and the last index at which it appears. Iterate through the keys and take the one with maximum last - first.

```
000: first is at 0, last is at 0
100: first is at 1, last is at 10
110: first is at 2, last is at 5
210: first is at 3, last is at 9
200: first is at 8, last is at 11
```

The best key is 100, since its sublist has length 9. The sublist is the (1+1)th element to the 10th.

This works because a sublist is balanced if and only if its first and last unnormalized histograms are the same up to adding a constant, which occurs if and only if the first and last normalized histograms are identical.

Comment: to search in N rows where each row starts and ends will take O(N^2). Other than that seems to work.

Comment: The whole point of hashing/radix sorting is that we don't have to search quadratically many possibilities.

Comment: @WeaselFox: you can just walk through the list once, for each entry check the code (eg: 200), if it's new code set index as first and last otherwise only as last. you can also store the current last-first maximum, so at the end of the iteration you have the solution. actually you don't even have to store the last index.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - Yes but there may be N different codes, and you have to search each code if its found or not. In interview puzzles and in theoretic questions its not usually OK to assume youre doing this in a hash table in O(1) time. You could use a different -sorted - data structure maybe.

Comment: At a higher level, I'm partitioning the indices by what their corresponding normalized row is. This was easiest to explain via hashing, but since each entry is between 0 and N, we can radix sort the indices in time O(N P) and then partition by comparing only adjacent elements in sorted order.

Comment: @Downvoter Sorry for spoiling your favorite interview question. (Or did you have a legitimate complaint?)

Comment: @WeaselFox: It only takes O(N^2) in O(1) space. This is not the case. If you look at the normalized histograms it should be obvious it's O(N).

Comment: @uty - even if you sort I cant see how you can determine if a histogram is new other than searching the sorted array for it. which is not done in O(1), more like O(log n). or maybe im not getting something. Great answer BTW.

Comment: `Now, normalize each row by subtracting the minimum element. The result is` could you explain why `4:100`? maybe that will be the key to me understanding what's happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If the memory usage is not important, it's easy...

You can give the matrix dimensions `N*p` and save in column **(i)** the value corresponding to how many elements `p` is looking  between **(i)** first element in the second vector...

After completing the matrix, you can search for column `i` that all of the elements in column `i` are not different. The maximum `i` is the answer.

Comment: do you seriously think someone will undestand this?

Comment: I think what Karoly meant to say was - welcome to Stack Overflow, your answer isn't clear.

Comment: i am sorry ,I can't speak English very well

Comment: Don't worry about it, all you need to do is explain your idea more.  Use an example, take a look at what other people are saying and try to relate your solution to theirs - for example, it sounds like your answer is similar to one above, so you might be on the right track. Use whatever tools you've got and don't get discouraged.  It takes a while to get the feel of things around here

Comment: @amin k: one of the reasons I joined here was to improve my english.. I know how hard it is to write in a lucid style the first time, just try to give your best ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I am here yet,and try to be  better,what is your idea?

Comment: @dfb :I am here yet,and try to be better,what is your idea?

Answer (score 3):

With randomization, you can get it down to linear time.  The idea is to replace each of the P values with a random integer, such that those integers sum to zero.  Now look for two prefix sums that are equal.   This allows some small chance of false positives, which we could remedy by checking our output.

In Python 2.7:

```
# input:
vec1 = [1, 2, 3]
P = len(vec1)
vec2 = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
N = len(vec2)
# Choose big enough integer B.  For each k in vec1, choose
# a random mod-B remainder r[k], so their mod-B sum is 0.
# Any P-1 of these remainders are independent.
import random
B = N*N*N
r = dict((k, random.randint(0,B-1)) for k in vec1)
s = sum(r.values())%B
r[vec1[0]] = (r[vec1[0]]+B-s)%B
assert sum(r.values())%B == 0
# For 0<=i<=N, let vec3[i] be mod-B sum of r[vec2[j]], for j<i.
vec3 = [0] * (N+1)
for i in range(1,N+1):
    vec3[i] = (vec3[i-1] + r[vec2[i-1]]) % B
# Find pair (i,j) so vec3[i]==vec3[j], and j-i is as large as possible.
# This is either a solution (subsequence vec2[i:j] is uniform) or a false
# positive.  The expected number of false positives is < N*N/(2*B) < 1/N.
(i, j)=(0, 0)
first = {}
for k in range(N+1):
    v = vec3[k]
    if v in first:
        if k-first[v] > j-i:
            (i, j) = (first[v], k)
    else:
        first[v] = k
# output:
print "Found subsequence from", i, "(inclusive) to", j, "(exclusive):"
print vec2[i:j]
print "This is either uniform, or rarely, it is a false positive."
```

Comment: Very nice idea! Still, your algorithm is O(N*P) just as uty's answer, but it is more space efficient. BTW: if you mostly take primes larger than N you reduce the possibility of false positives. Unfortunately, one of the substitutes can't be a prime since you need the sum to be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an observation: you can't get a uniformly distributed sequence that is not a multiplication of `P` in length. This implies that you only have to check the sub-sequences of `N` that are `P`, `2P`, `3P`... long - `(N/P)^2` such sequences.

Comment: and then if you are clever you get an O(N^2/P) solution.. unfortunately he needs better

Answer (score 0):

You can get this down to O(N) time, with no dependence on P by enhancing uty's solution.

For each row, instead of storing the normalized counts of each element, store a hash of the normalized counts while only keeping the normalized counts for the current index. During each iteration, you need to first update the normalized counts, which has an amortized cost of O(1) if each decrement of a count is paid for when it is incremented. Next you recompute the hash. The key here is that the hash needs to be easily updatable following an increment or decrement of one of the elements of the tuple that is being hashed.

At least one way of doing this hashing efficiently, with good theoretical independence guarantees is shown in the answer to [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3390/is-there-a-hash-function-for-a-collection-i-e-multi-set-of-integers-that-has). Note that the O(lg P) cost for computing the exponential to determine the amount to add to the hash can be eliminated by precomputing the exponentials modulo the prime in with a total running time of O(P) for the precomputation, giving a total running time of O(N + P) = O(N).